# Extract number from HTML attribute with regex

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I have to extract a number in Java (using jsoup) from a code similar to this one:

```
<i class="name" title="There are 3 elements" ></i>
```

(3 is the number to extract)

I have tried with this regex:

```
i[title~=There\\s*+are\\s*=[0-9]+\\s*elements]
```

but it doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: From what I can tell, `jsoup` is used to select items based on regular expressions, not extract data from them. Is what you're trying to do actually possible?

Comment: Try this `title="There are ([0-9]+) elements"` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI8rO6/1) and get the first matched group

Comment: OR try `(?<=title="There are )[0-9]+(?= elements")` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI8rO6/2) without using any grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
title="There\\s+are\\s+([0-9]+)\\s+elements"
```

Try this.grab the capture or group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/3

The reason yours is not working is because you have included everything inside `[]` character class which does not maintain sequence and is just a pool of characters to chose from.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
i[title~=There (is|are) (\d+) element.]
```